# How to query MySQL where the parent name of a post is contained in a column of database table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Currently, I am able to fetch results where a column matches the title of a post. I have duplicate post titles which have unique parent posts. For example, I have a name `James` whose parent post is a country `England` and `James` whose parent post is `Australia`.

I created a variable `$title = get_the_title( $post_id );` When I query `SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '$title'` I am able to fetch results of `James` but this is also pulling `James` from other `countries`. I don't wish to hard code the country name into the query. The columns in the database which I wish to compare the `country` with contains this kind of data:

```
country                           | name
England - some random text        | James
Australia - more text             | James
Northern Ireland - even more text | Mary
```

So basically, I am comparing the parent name of a post say `/people/england/james` which in this case is `england`, (people is the post type) against the column in database `country` which should find `England - some random text`   and return the correct `James`.

So to break this down I am looking for something along the lines of

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = '$title' AND (country column part before the hyphen contains parent post name.)
```

Using the slug of parent may not be appropriate considering it contain hyphens for countries like `people/republic-of-ireland/mary` so sticking with the parent name `Republic of Ireland -`  will be a better option. How do you achieve this kind of query?

With Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using PHP as well as MySQL you should be looking to use "Explode" logic on your post.

```
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string(str_replace($_POST['Country'], '-', ' ')); //Get the country and replace the dashes with spaces

mysqli_query('SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = "' . $title . '" AND country LIKE "' . $country . ' - %"');
```

Be careful to escape your strings or use PDO binding here since, you would be very vulnerable otherwise placing variables directly into your query.

Also of note, depending on your DB's character encoding, you might need to wrap a `Lower` and a `strtolower()` around your MySQL and PHP strings respectively, since they will otherwise not match "Republic-of-Ireland" to "Republic Of Ireland"

Comment: You sure the comment in your code is correct? Also you do not need to terminate query with `;`.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcinOrlowski, I was on auto-pilot for some of that. Good call

Comment: About the safety, I'm appending `$wpdb->prepare` to the queries. That's enough? So that the query becomes 
`global $wpdb;  $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = "' . $title . '" AND country LIKE "' . $country . ' - %"')); ` Also this will be *preprocessed* so that the user sees the data relevant to that page. For example, if the user clicks a link `/people/england/james` the data is preloaded so that they see data specific to the page if that makes sense. I don't think user input is available to visitors. Correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: The problem here would be if someone manually changed the link to be something malicious. If a user can access it, a user can change it. They can edit a link on the frontend, or the things which generate it. The prepared statements are a step in the right direction, just look into the PDO->bindParameter() syntax (if you are using PDO), it is the standard and safest way to proceed.

Comment: The answer above, specifically this line `$country = mysqli_real_escape_string(str_replace($_POST['Country'], '-', ' '));` I think what it's doing is separating the `England` from `England - some random text` and then allowing you to make the query. I don't think it's pulling the parent name of a post. That means I have to create a variable `$country = get_the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) );` and then this `$country = mysqli_real_escape_string(str_replace($_POST['Country'], '-', ' '));` Is this correct? Pardon my ignorance

Comment: $country = get_the_title( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) );  global $wpdb;  $results = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * from mytable WHERE name = "' . $title . '" AND country LIKE "' . $country . ' - %"'));  So that once the $country pulls the parent post England, it then compares it with the value in the database country column  value $country . ' - %'

Comment: That should be fine, I suppose. I suppose it depends on how the Wordpress`get_post_parent_id` processes the input from the url. Otherwise it looks good